# Substitution variables in DOS SET

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables, cmd

I am trying to do this in a DOS CMD Script:

```
@setlocal
@for /L %%X in (1,1,10) do @call :label1 %%X
@endlocal
@exit /b

:label1
@set I=%1
@set /P A%I%=SET A%I% to?
@echo You entered %%A%%I%%
exit /b
```

However I cannot get it to echo the actual entered value. I have tried all variations on the echo line.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your output, you could use `call echo You entered %%A%I%%%`.

But it would be better to use delayed expansion so that special characters like & and | can never cause you problems: `echo You entered !A%I%!`

In order to use delayed expansion, you need to enable it with `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`.

Helpful hint 1 - Put `@echo off` at the top of your script. Then you never need to use `@` in any of the following commands.

Helpful hint 2 - You should explicitly clear any existing variable value prior to using SET /P. You can't be sure it is not already defined. If the user simply presses `<Enter>` without entering anything, then the existing value will be preserved.

Helpful hint 3 - You don't even need the `I` variable. You can simply use the `%1` parameter wherever you have `%I%`.

Helpful hint 4 - Better yet, you don't even need to call a subroutine.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%X in (1,1,10) do (
  set "A%%X="
  set /P "A%%X=SET A%%X to? "
  echo You entered !A%%X!
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The first suggestion, %%A%I%%%, did not work. It ends up displaying: "You entered %A1%", "You entered %A2%", etc.  However your second suggestion without a call, did work.

Comment: @Neilw - Hmmm... the `CALL echo %%A%I%%%` version works for me. Are you sure you put CALL before your ECHO? But the delayed expansion method is better anyway.

Comment: oh good point. I forgot the CALL eho.

On a related note, in your delayedexpansion example, how do I permit the entry of special characters like semicolon and comma?

Comment: @Neilw - ???? There is nothing more to do. The user can enter any character. ECHO using delayed expansion will print it out just fine. Make sure you do NOT use CALL with the delayed expansion technique.

Comment: Thanks for your help. One last roadblock: how do I compare a variable to a double quote ". E.g., 

SET Q="

IF !Q! equ """ echo YES

Comment: @Neilw - `if "!q!"==^""" echo YES`  If your question has been answered , you should accept the answer by clicking on the check mark.